# How to protect copyrighted multimedia files when downloading to android phone?

Tags: javascript, android, encryption, react-native, drm

I'm building an application that allows users to upload multimedia files they create (audio, video, graphic) via my web frontend, and then other users can stream/download the files to their phone using my mobile app. I'm building the mobile app with react native. The problem is with the android platform-- when the files are downloaded, they show up in the Downloads folder, which means they can be copied, moved, and opened from other apps.

Since the file contents are copyrighted, I need to find a way to

1. prevent these files from being listed in the Downloads folder

and / or

2. prevent other apps from opening them.

Apps like Spotify and Netflix manage to do it (e.g. if you download a playlist from Spotify, you can't see them anywhere else on your phone). I believe some kind of encryption/decryption scheme is involved. But I don't know enough about it. Would appreciate any insight on how to go about this.

Comment: There is no 100% foolproof way to achieve this, if the phone can play the media offline, then it is possible to extract the media too, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

As Luke says, there is no 100% protection, but usual approach is to encrypt the files and to use a DRM system to manage the secure transition of the key from the server to the client Android device.

Android devices (generally) come with widevide DRM built in and this is probably the most common one used, but the system supports other DRMs also and device vendors may add different ones.

If you are prepared to accept a less secure encryption, but one which may be good enough for your needs, then MPEG DASH includes a 'clearkey' option which ExoPlayer supports. If you do go this way it is worth checking on the latest ExoPlayer status as this feature is being worked on at the moment:

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3178